# .bat file not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have to call two bat files.

One name `cbpp_job` and other `upload.bat`.

In first .bat files, I have called `cbppservice.exe` and after that I have call `upload.bat`.

**cbpp_job.bat**

```
call d:\csdb_exe\CBPPService.exe
call ftp -n -s:"d:\csdb\Success\upload.bat" xxxx.produrl.com
```

**upload.bat**

```
user XXXXXX
XXXXXXXXX

PUT ZA1P.FTP.CBPP.INTRFACE.GRP(+1) 'ZA1P.FTP.CBPP.INTRFACE.GRP(+1)'
BYE

EXIT
```

But when I call `csdb_job` through command prompt it works well. When I scheduled it in task scheduler it only calls `cbppservice.exe` and it is not doing the `ftp`.

The operating System is windows server 2008.

Comment: For what it's worth, a script file for `ftp` doesn't necessarily need a `.bat` extension, but that shouldn't be what's causing the problem.  What I wonder is, does the ACL of `d:\csdb\success\upload.bat` allow reading by the machine's system account?  Task scheduler doesn't run with the same permissions as the desktop user.  Are there any hints about failures in your event logs that might indicate the source of the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If your event viewer doesn't show you why your script is failing, Try modifying **cbpp_job.bat** to redirect stderr to a log file.

```
(
    d:\csdb_exe\CBPPService.exe
    ftp -n -s:"d:\csdb\Success\upload.bat" xxxx.produrl.com
) 2>"c:\csdbtask.log"
```

Maybe that'll help you figure out why task scheduler is failing.